# Mod redirct error

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

when I used the SSL fot my website i got following error.
in error log. and site shows me default page instead of actual page.

I got following error.
.htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here

Comment: Don't bother; this is a "wham, bam" but no "thank you, mam" user. Four questions, zero accepted answers.

Answer (score 2):

Is `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All` on in your server configuration? Typically, HTTPS and HTTP sites use different configuration sections or files. Make sure your site is properly configured.